# cocos2d MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

i tried to insert a mail tool in my app.... my app is based on the cocos2d engine

the Toolbar (at the top ->cancel,send...) is visible but i can't see the other parts of the mfMailComposerViewController view :-(

code:

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet {   
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker setSubject:@"my message"];

// Set up recipients
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];  
[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

// Attach an image to the email
UIImage *screenshot = [[Director sharedDirector] screenShotUIImage];
NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshot);
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"AdMotiv"]; 

// Fill out the email body text
NSString *emailBody = @"test";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
[[picker view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,320.0f, 480.0f)];

[[picker view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
[[picker view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,320.0f, 480.0f)];
//[[[VariableStore sharedInstance] parentView] setTransform: CGAffineTransformIdentity];
//[[[VariableStore sharedInstance] parentView] setBounds : CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 480.0f, 320.0f)];

UITextField *textfeld = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0f, 50.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
[[picker view] addSubview:textfeld];


[[[VariableStore sharedInstance] window]addSubview:picker.view];
[[[VariableStore sharedInstance] window] makeKeyAndVisible];


[picker release];
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I too have the same problem. My control is not even entering in to the mail controller. I used a selector in cocos2d to display mail controller. 

      -(void)goToFirstScreen:(id)sender
       {

    CCScene *Scene = [CCScene node];
    CCLayer *Layer = [mailME node];

    [Scene addChild:Layer];

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene: Scene];
}    

mailMe is the class name of the mail controller. I think it is wrong  to add in this way. How to add it in cocos2d ?
Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

heyyyy finally. i've got it working ... it seems like the trouble was some animations ... ... i've got it like this now:

on init:

> emailController = [[UIViewController
>   alloc] init]; [[[CCDirector
>   sharedDirector] openGLView]
>   addSubview:emailController.view];

on button click:

> [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
>   [[CCDirector sharedDirector]
>   stopAnimation];
>
> MFMailComposeViewController *picker =
>   [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]
>   init]; picker.mailComposeDelegate =
>   self;
>
> [picker setSubject:@"TEST"]; [picker
>   setMessageBody:@"JAJAJA" isHTML:YES];
>
> [emailController
>   presentModalViewController:picker
>   animated:YES]; [picker release];

delegate method for MFMailComposeViewController

> -(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller
>   didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
>   error:(NSError*)error {   [[CCDirector
>   sharedDirector] resume];  [[CCDirector
>   sharedDirector] startAnimation];
>     [controller
>   dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
>   }

Answer (score 0):

in the last bit there, change picker to self, and it should work. something to double-check, have you set your class as a delegate? i.e. MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate in the header? if not, then it won't be getting the messages.

btw this is in response to the answer you posted, not the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried with this code and works ( not for the animation, I don'know why, but the picker is removed correctly :)

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
```

{
    //[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker.view removeFromSuperview];

}

Answer (score 0):

Few steps are required to implement inApp email functionality.

Step1: Add the MessageUI frameWork.

Step2: In the .h file,
    #import "MessageUI/MessageUI.h". 
Also add delegate MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, like and the UIViewController *emailMe;

Step3: In the .m file Add these lines of code in the init function

```
CCMenuItem *emailItem = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString: @"Email"     target:selfselector:@selector(emailCallback)];
CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: emailItem, nil];
    menu.position = ccp(50,50);
    [self addChild:menu];

    emailMe = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:emailController.view];
```

step 4 : add these methods in .m

```
-(void)emailCallback
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];

    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"Email test "];
    [picker setMessageBody:@"finally its working " isHTML:YES];

    [emailMe presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];

    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

and run the app its done :)

Comment: @PriyaKerala: is it not working at all ? elaborate a little bit.

Comment: i used this code and then my simulator shows a blank screen nothing related to the mail is getting displayed

Comment: Its working in iPad, But not in iPhone. 
<MFMailComposeViewController: 0x152db740> on <UIViewController: 0xc637d60> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!